# URL key for specified store already exists Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I know there are so many questions already asked related to this issue. But mine one is little difference. I created one custom module for import the products in Magento 2. In which  categories will be created automatically if not exists. Its working fine. When there is no category in store but when there is any category in store and I try to define it in csv file then I am getting "**URL key for specified store already exists.**" error. I already checked so many answers and tried so many things but not get proper success.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, You may need to delete the URL Rewrites:

**MARKETING > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't think its good idea to remove the URL Rewrite entries. It will affect the site when we remove it?

Comment: Yes, be careful. Seem that the url rewrites (products, categories) will be generated after running reindex. However, if you have some specific urls (cms url rewrites), they are not generated again.

Comment: is there any way instead of delete delete the entry of URL Rewrites for resolve this issue?

Comment: Currently, I have no idea. It's better if we take a look the Url rewrite module, try to find the root cause. Try to use Plugin or Reference to add our custom part. Or, creating our custom one.

Answer (score 2):

Just like every product, every category has a unique URL key too and you can’t have two products or categories with same URL key.

You can access the URL key of any category by selecting the category from your admin panel.

[image]

So when you try to add a category through CSV that already exists you’ll get the error "URL key for specified store already exists."

Make sure new categories have a unique name and a URL key.

Answer (score 0):

After looking on internet for days I couldn't find exact solution of this.
Then I found if we change the URLKEY of the category it will not show this error so I have tried this.

```
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath())
            ->setParentId($parentId)
            ->setName('test1')
            ->setIsActive(true)
            ->setUrlKey(rand(1,1000000000));
        $category->save();
```

I have used random function to add category in database with random nunmber using `->setUrlKey(rand(1,1000000000));` you can add any thing in this like duplicate category name with some random number etc.
and errors gone if it helps you give an UP. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue in more than 3-4 projects.

If you want to resolve this issue, you can upgrade your version with latest one or try below code logic:

Try this solution by overriding below function in your custom module :)

Path: vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/Storage

```
protected function doReplace(array $urls){ 
    $this->deleteOldUrls($urls); 
    $data = [];
    $storeId_requestPaths = [];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $storeId = $url->getStoreId();
        $requestPath = $url->getRequestPath();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM url_rewrite where store_id = $storeId and request_path = '$requestPath'";
        $exists = $this->connection->fetchOne($sql); 
        if ($exists) continue;
        $storeId_requestPaths[] = $storeId . '-' . $requestPath;
        $data[] = $url->toArray();
    }

    // Remove duplication data;
    $n = count($storeId_requestPaths);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {
            if ($storeId_requestPaths[$i] == $storeId_requestPaths[$j]) {
                unset($data[$j]);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        $this->insertMultiple($data);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {
        /** @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[] $urlConflicted */
        $urlConflicted = [];
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $urlFound = $this->doFindOneByData(
                [
                    UrlRewriteData::REQUEST_PATH => $url->getRequestPath(),
                    UrlRewriteData::STORE_ID => $url->getStoreId(),
                ]
            );
            if (isset($urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID])) {
                $urlConflicted[$urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID]] = $url->toArray();
            }
        }
        if ($urlConflicted) {
            throw new \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Exception\UrlAlreadyExistsException(
                __('URL key for specified store already exists.'),
                $e,
                $e->getCode(),
                $urlConflicted
            );
        } else {
            throw $e->getPrevious() ?: $e;
        }
    }

    return $urls;
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Thanks,

Ketan T.