# Magento 2 URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I'm trying to move my Category Wincomm but I keep getting this message.
[image]

I have 2 Store Views and I have changed the url using `Marketing -> URL Rewrites` but the message keeps returning. I've also tried to delete the category and re-import it but that didn't work.

I have checked these solution but they didn't work.

- [URL key for specified store already exists Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172317/url-key-for-specified-store-already-exists-magento-2)
- [The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277923/the-value-specified-in-the-url-key-field-would-generate-a-url-that-already-exist)
- [M2: The URL key for the selected store already exists](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276365/m2-the-url-key-for-the-selected-store-already-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Marketing -> URL Rewrites and , delete the conflict url after rewrite the your category again.