# Duplicate url issue when removing products from category in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite

When i try to remove products from category https://prnt.sc/vl7rt3, i get duplicate url error.
https://prnt.sc/vkscz9.

I know how to resolve it. but need to understand when a product is removed from a subcategory - how is it generating a duplicate url?

Can any one please explain me this?

Comment: check the solution in below link, [https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/324242/92172](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/324242/92172)

Answer (score 0):

Put backslashes before urls.It may help you

Comment: I want to know the reason of this issue. As i already said, i know how to resolve it. I want to understand when a product is removed from a subcategory - how is it generating a duplicate url?